# Вывести числа которые ниже главной диагонали матрицы

Tags: c++

Для каждого столбца заданной матрицы найти сумму элементов, расположенных ниже главной
диагонали. Составить и напечатать матрицу.

Сделал генерирование матрицы, для удобства вывел главную диагональ, хотел для начала вывести столбцы, но оно выводит как-то не так как я думал https://i.stack.imgur.com/aizg1.png, нужно именно столбец, а потом добавить все числа с него, т.е 48 43 0 13 и добавило это, аналогично и с другим столбцом 28 21 12 и тд.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/unSRT.png

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int matr[5][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            matr[i][j] = rand() % 50;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            cout << matr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

    cout << '\n';
    cout << "Diagonal";
    cout << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << '\n' << matr[i][i] << " ";
    }

    cout << '\n';
    cout << "suma chisel";
    cout << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            cout << matr[i][j] << "  ";
        }
    }



    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А какой вопрос?

Comment: Как сделать чтобы оно вывело и добавило элементы столбца который ниже главной диагонали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь вывод новой строки после внутреннего цикла

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) 
  { 
    cout << matr[i][j] << " "; 
  }
cout << "\n "; // <- здесь
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, только если не сложно, как добавить элементы этих столбцов которые вывелись? Как на скрине  https://i.imgur.com/H9zb6N1.png

Comment: Не понял. Куда добавить?

Comment: Ну чтобы оно ещё ниже вывело суму элементов этого же столбца, скрин кидал выше

Comment: Создать вектор, в него посчитать сумму столбцов и точно так же вывести.